# Group of continuous automorphisms of cylindrical plane is a lie group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

How do I prove this theorem?

> Theorem:  The group of continuous automorphisms of a cylindrical plane is a lie group.

In this context, cylindrical means the Laguerre plane.

I found a paper it says that about the benz plane.